# What it's the time complexity of 2D array not strictly square?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, time-complexity, big-o

Let's assume we have a 2D array that looks like this

```
array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6]]
```

As you can see, it's not a square 2D array, and we have a function that sums all the values in it.

```
def sum_values(array):
     total = 0
     for i in array:
         for j in i:
             total += j
     return total
```

So the question is, is the time complexity still O(n^2)? or something like O(ab) or something else?

Comment: complexity is `O(1)`, equal to number of elements, you touch every element only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define `n` as the size of the input matrix and say the algorithm is `O(n)` or you can define `n` as the number of rows and `m` as the number of columns in the input and say the algorithm is `O(n*m)`